# Zend db update value not being set

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework

I'm not sure what's missing with this update call, here's my code:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_ProductContaminant();
$db = $table->getAdapter();

$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);
$data = array('value' => '999');
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('product_id = ?', $q['product_id']);
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('contaminant_id = ?', $k);
$table->update($data, $where);

print $db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQuery();
```

And the profiler output is:

```
UPDATE `product_contaminants` SET `value` = ? WHERE (product_id = '4802') AND (contaminant_id = 69)
```

Why isn't 'value' being populated??

Answer (score 2):

Value isn't populated because getQuery will only return a prepared statement with parameter placeholders. If you want the parameters used when it updates try this:

```
$db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQueryParams()
```

More info [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html).

Comment: OK, that seems to be correct:  [1] => 999. Why isn't it getting into the statement?

Comment: Of course, you cant update an empty row, can you?? Thanks for your help Tim!!